# Are modules a good idea in typescript? Or are they just added complexity?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I come from the Java/C# world where namespaces are absolutely necessary. However, [comments like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869502/calling-a-typescript-module-from-javascript-via-requirejs) make me think that modules are of no utility in typescript (and javascript). For large typescript/javascript programs (probably several hundred .ts/.js files by the time we're done), are modules a good practice or do they just get in the way?

ps - I know that opinion questions are not allowed here. But, IMO, this is more a "please explain how javascript works" question.

Comment: It totally depends. There's nothing about this question that strikes me as "how JavaScript works".

Comment: My opinion: Modules are useful as a means of encapsulation, making huge systems manageable.  But many libraries load modules via deep namespaces adding to perceived complexity. Deep namespaces are not useful in JavaScript where modules can be dynamically loaded -- they are necessary for certain compiled languages without built-in packages control where there is a huge library and you must keep track of things.  AMD modules, however, are very useful.  Notice that if you have a large number of modules available, the names of the modules themselves may be expressed over a deep namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Having a deep namespace hierarchy is mostly an overkill. Having a single top level namespace is definitely a good idea though.

e.g.

```
module appName{
    class Foo{}
}
```

instead of

```
class Foo{}
```

But not so if you are using already using external modules (commonjs / requirejs) as they isolate code for each file.

Comment: Yeah, that's fundamental to my question. We're using requirejs and each "namespace" is in a distinct .ts or .js file. The way javascript works, do modules add anything to that?

Comment: @DavidThielen not at all